# display only records with continuous coverage

Tags: sql

I have sample data as below. Even though i have duplicates in the data i want to result as below

duplicates can be ignored.

```
Sample data
123456  2019-03-01  2199-12-31
123456  2019-03-01  2019-12-31 
123456  2019-03-01  2199-12-31
123456  2020-01-01  2199-12-31
123456  1920-01-01  2019-02-28
```

Output is required as below

```
123456  1920-01-01  2019-02-28 
123456  2019-03-01  2199-12-31
```

can some please help me write a SQL display the out with continuous coverage records with end date as 2199/12/31

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Why is `1920-01-01->2019-02-28, 2019-03-01->2020-12-31, 2020-01-01->2199-12-31` not a valid example of continuous coverage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by unpivoting the data and keeping track of periods when the net number is greater than 0:

```
with t as (
      select id, start as dt, 1 as inc
      from <table> t
      union all
      select id, end, -1 as inc
      from <table> t
     )
select id, min(dt), max(next_dt)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when net_ins = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by dt) as grp,
             lead(dt) over (partition by id order by dt) as next_dt
      from (select id, dt,
                   sum(sum(inc)) over (partition by id order by dt) as net_ins
            from t
            group by id, dt
           ) t
      ) t
where net_ins > 0
group by id, grp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ddb7d7735ef197aa3a9e353596c3c087) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @jay . . . I added a db<>fiddle and fixed a couple of things.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff .. Appreciate your help. ..yes, I just saw the DB file and  It worked for oracle . I am trying to do the sameon HIVE (bigdata) but sum(sum()) over  not working. Do you have any suggestions on HIVE as well for the smilar data

Comment: That should work in Hive.  You can try using a subquery for the aggregation and then the window function in an outer query.

Comment: ok Thanks.. forsome reason its not working in HIVE,anyway i will look into it

Comment: Can you please help me with hive quey as well as i am not able too